# The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store

Tags: android, android-workmanager

When I added work manager library to android studio and run the app it crashes with this error:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 37816 of [c255889bd9]
    (14) os_unix.c:37816: (13) lstat(/data/user/0/com.example/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb) - 
    (1) Process m.example : Pid (13632) Uid (11395) Euid (11395) Gid (11395) Egid (11395)
    (1) osStat failed "/data/user/0/com.example/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb" due to error (13)
    (1) osStat failed "/data/user/0/com.first.academy/no_backup" due to error (13)
    (1) Stat of /data/user/0/com.example : st_mode(40700) st_uid(11385) st_gid(11385) st_ino(164253)
    (1) Stat of /data/user/0 : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(131074)
    (1) Stat of /data/user : st_mode(40711) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(655366)
    (1) Stat of /data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(2)
    .....


E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.example/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1806 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EACCES[1806]): Could not open database
...

E/WM-ForceStopRunnable: The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1806 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EACCES[1806]): Could not open database
...

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
    Process: com.example, PID: 13632
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store.
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:115)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1806 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EACCES[1806]): Could not open database
....
```

This is the library i added:

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"
```

When I remove this library it works again. I don't know if the problem with the device or the app.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910397/workmanager-crashes-trying-to-enqueue-unique-periodic-work-in-applicationoncrea

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer I created a new project to test this, i didn't add any code to the project.

Comment: Getting same crash in only one device. App is not getting open. @ameencarpenter Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by adding this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge">
    <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
 </provider>
```

I got this from the documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration

Comment: It seems this solution is not enough to fix it. This is done on the AndroidManifest in my project, but we have the same issue here.

Comment: Please update to androidx work to 2.8.1
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Just change Workmanager initilization in Application class by following code

```
val configuration: androidx.work.Configuration = androidx.work.Configuration.Builder().build()
        configuration.initializationExceptionHandler.let {
            this.deleteDatabase(WorkManagerImpl::class.java.simpleName)
            this.getSharedPreferences(WorkManagerImpl::class.java.simpleName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                ?.edit()?.clear()?.apply()
            this.let { WorkManager.initialize(it, androidx.work.Configuration.Builder().build()) }
        }
```