# IllegalStateException: The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-workmanager, android-database

My app is not going to open. When i try to open app it immediately close with below crash.

It is happening in only one device Redmi note 10s.(Android 11)

It seems issue with Workmanager, but didn't found any solution

```
The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store.Error Message: The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store.StackTracejava.lang.IllegalStateException: The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store.
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:120)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/data/user/0/study.pedagogy.android/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb': Directory /data/user/0/study.pedagogy.android/no_backup doesn't exist
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:252)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:918)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:898)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:762)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:751)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:373)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:622)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:399)
    at androidx.work.impl.model.SystemIdInfoDao_Impl.getWorkSpecIds(SystemIdInfoDao_Impl.java:120)
    at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.reconcileJobs(SystemJobScheduler.java:284)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.cleanUp(ForceStopRunnable.java:199)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable(ForceStopRunnable.java:165)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:102)
    ... 4 more
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:224)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: same issue. found any solution?

Comment: if you resolved this issue then pls share with us. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77458951/3522570 Check this answer