# Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store

Tags: android-sqlite, androidx, android-workmanager

There is [a similar question for Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434025/the-file-system-on-the-device-is-in-a-bad-state-workmanager-cannot-access-the-a) about this crash. I wanted to add my case with more details.

First, this app crash happens only occasionally. It seems to happen only on Android TV devices. The following is from Sony BRAVIA_VH2 (BRAVIA VH2):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException

Type: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store.
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run (ForceStopRunnable.java:153)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run (SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open (SQLiteConnection.java:215)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open (SQLiteConnection.java:197)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner (SQLiteDatabase.java:915)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open (SQLiteDatabase.java:895)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (SQLiteDatabase.java:759)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (SQLiteDatabase.java:748)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:374)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableOrReadableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:231)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.innerGetDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:222)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:151)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction (RoomDatabase.kt)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction (RoomDatabase.kt)
  at androidx.work.impl.model.SystemIdInfoDao_Impl.getWorkSpecIds (SystemIdInfoDao_Impl.java:163)
  at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.reconcileJobs (SystemJobScheduler.java:311)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.cleanUp (ForceStopRunnable.java:278)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable (ForceStopRunnable.java:242)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run (ForceStopRunnable.java:134)
```

dependency:

```
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'
```

This crash happens only on a few devices. Could anyone offer a tip about how to remedy this?

**[Update] 2023-04-26**

- This crash seems to happen only on BRAVIA VH2 devices.
- It can happen over 10 times a day. I doubt the users notice them. I
  wonder why Google Play reports it as a crash.
- The following is the only code related to androidx.work that is in a try-catch block:

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WidgetUpdateWorker.class).build(); 
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(WidgetUpdateWorker.WIDGET_UPDATE_WORK, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, oneTimeWorkRequest);
```

**[Update] 2023-04-27**

One crash from Lenovo X306F has been reported.

**[Update] 2023-05-01**

The app itself does not use SQLiteDatabase at all.  I wonder if one of its dependencies uses it.

Comment: I got same issue have you found any solution for this? :)

Comment: @GauravMandlik thanks for reporting it. No, I have not found a clue despite many efforts. It is very frustrating.

Comment: Same in Google Pixel 5 Android API 33

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue on Pixel 5(API 33).

Adding `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'` solved for me.

Comment: As stated in my original question, "implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'" has been there.